# What is the value of hs_language for a codeset conversion from cp850 to utf8 for the Oracle gateway

Tags: oracle, informix

I have setup an Oracle gateway connected to an Informix IDS database created with an utf8 codeset. 
In my dg4imfx file I have HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252.
With HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=DEBUG it seems that the Oracle client sends the value of e acute in the update statement with a cp850 codeset page:

```
00: 55504441 54452022 646F7373 6965725F [UPDATE "XXXXXXX_]
10: 616A5F74 65737422 20534554 20226C69 [XX_XXXX" SET "CC]
20: 65755F73 746F636B 61676522 203D2027 [CC_CCCCCCCC" = ']
30: **82**27 [.']
```

If I run:

```
echo é|iconv -f utf8 -t cp850|xxd
```

it gives 0x82.

What advice can you give about the HS_LANGUAGE parameter syntax use?

Comment: Did you try `HS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8PC850`?

Comment: no, sorry i didn't find a clear explanation about hs_language. i will try it. what did WE8 means ?

Comment: `WE8` stands for "Western 8 bit". Run `SELECT VALUE AS ORACLE_CHARSET, UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE) AS IANA_NAME FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES WHERE PARAMETER = 'CHARACTERSET';` to get mapping of Oracle name to commonly used terms.

Comment: What is codeset informix ids database?  What is codeset oracle database?  What is `NLS_LANG` environment variable when start oracle process? `HS_LANGUAGE` is codeset of a heterogeneous data source.

Comment: informix codeset is fr_FR.UTF8 for the database. i'm waiting for oracle db codeset. nls_lang isn't present on the gateway may be in oracle server env.thanks

Comment: informix codeset is fr_FR.UTF8 for the database. NLS_LANG is FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252 for the oracle db server. So am i suppose to set the HS_LANGUAGE for the gateway to the same value?  The gateway is on a third server.

Comment: solved with gateway 12.1 and NLS_LANG is FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252